# Rails queue a calculation after_destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I'm in the process of implementing resque to recalculate some thing after a model instance is destroyed. To do this I'm using an `after_destroy` callback. Before I implement the calculation I want to test to ensure that the calculations will be executed on a different subset.

So to test this I am using `rails c --sandbox` and am getting some confusing information. Here is the output:

```
> @run = Run.new(status: 0, archived: false)
> @run.save 
> I then print the Run.count and get 200
> @run.destroy!
> I then print the Run.count and get 200
```

Note I'm using `after_save` and `after_destroy` to print out the Run.count numbers that are equal when I think they should be different.

My end goal is when certain conditions are changed add a calculation to a resque queue and continue on.

The main question I have is. Why aren't the number changed? Will the specific run be flagged for deletion and not included in my calculation query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a callback executes, it executes in a transaction. It may cause problems when you perform your calculations before the transaction ends. Try to use `after_commit` callback, which performs after the transaction ends.

```
after_commit :do_something, on: :create
after_commit :do_something, on: :destroy
```

Comment: If I query the DB to calculate the sum of all of one particular variable in an `after_destroy` callback will it include the one being destroyed?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "calculate the sum of all of one particular variable".

Comment: A `Product` model has a `cost` variable and I want to update the cost of all Products after one is destroyed.

Comment: Forget about all I had written. I was wrong. However it can be true for some kinds of db and depending on a rails version. The common behavior is that when you perform DELETE request, the next SELECT(COUNT) request should return `n-1` result, whether it happens in a transaction or not. I think the problem might be in DB requests caching.